# Redirect users to login page when they click to edit MediaWiki

Tags: php, json, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I need to redirect users that aren't logged in to the login page when they try to edit a page on my wiki, and then once they have logged in, redirects them back to the edit page.

I found this MediaWiki extension that does the job I am looking for (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ForceLogin) but it doesn't appear to be up to date and I couldn't get it working on the newest version of MediaWiki (1.31.0).

I tried to remake the extension myself (here: https://github.com/JoshBigGuns/ForceLogin) but don't have much experience with PHP and writing extensions.

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks - Josh